# Issue with environment variables JAVA and Android for using cordova (Linux 16.04)

Tags: java, android, cordova, environment-variables

I am trying to build an android app with cordova. I have followed each step and I have solved many issues but in this last step, when I input the command "cordova build", I get the following message:

> "Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
>   ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
>   ANDROID_HOME=/home/javiertxu/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
>   Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
>   or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
>   in your path, or install Android Studio"

I will show here the file ~/.bashrc with my environment variables.

[Image with ~/.bashrc content file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x179G.png)

One strange thing is when I "echo JAVA_HOME" it prints an empty message, then I think that the real issue is relationed with that (you can see it in the following image) [empty echo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7lSe.png), or maybe the file .bashrc is not the correct file which I should to modify.

When I use the command "readlink -f $(which java)" I get this direction "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java". If I print $ANDROID_HOME I get /home/javiertxu/Android/Sdk.

This is all the information I can provide, so I hope that someone can help me solve this.

Thanks.

Image of .profile:
[~/.profile content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KOUh.png)

Comment: how is this related to JavaScript in anyway (other than the mentiion of Cordova)?

Comment: @Randy_Castburn: Because probably someone who is a javascript developer has experience with cordova. It is only one tag...

Comment: is it possible you are using `root`'s `.bashrc` (via sudo perhaps) rather than your personal `.bashrc`?

Comment: @RandyCasburn In this case I have modify the personal .bashrc. I did not modify the root's file but If I modify it I get the same empty variable.

Comment: OK. Then move your environment variable settings to your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks for your answer. I have add an image with the .profile file content at the end of my question. I have add the paths there but I continue with exactly the same issue.

Comment: Did you log out and log back in? Those changes won't take effect until then. If that still does not work, then it is time to move to the `~./bash_profile` - but log out and back in first to ensure `~/.profile` changes truly didn't work.